# How to create formtastic form with multiple language support (Internationalization)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, formtastic, dropdownbox

I need to set up two languages for a single form using internationalization.

This is the proposed form page

```
<%= semantic_form_for @detail do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :dob  %> 
    <%= f.input :gender, :as => :radio, :label => "Gender", :collection => [["Male", 'male'], ["Female", 'female']] %>  
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is wk.yml file

```
wk: 
formtastic:
    labels:
      detail:
        dob: "Data of birtha"
        name: "Youre Nama"
        gender: "Gendera""
```

This is en.yml file

```
en: 
  formtastic:
    labels:
      detail:
        dob: "Date of Birth"
        name: "Your Name"
        gender: "gender"
```

I have added Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.i18n_lookups_by_default = true in formtastic.rb initializer.

I was successful in using en.yml.

I need to switch from 'en' to 'wk' and vise-verse.

How to achieve it via drop down box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something related to formstatic, but rather to your rails code.

All you have to do in order to switch to wk is

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

```
I18n.locale = :wk
```

In order to let your client to choose his language for the website, probably a good place to start is on this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

If all you want is to update the form (and not the rest of the website) in different languages on a user action, like selecting the language from a select box, you can use an ajax listener on the select box, that could require something like "http://www.yourwebsite.com/:locale/form/new" which will answer with an ajax action and will replace your form with the selected language (so on :locale you will pass the value of your select box for the language).

Comment: <%=link_to "EN", url_for(:locale => "en")%> I use this code to convert language in a normal rails page. But its not working in the case of Formtastic

Comment: Just to be sure, there is some space on your wk.yml file right? Because I'm seeing that the second line on the language file is aligned to the left, pretty user its a formatting issue on stackoverflow, but I'm asking just in case

Comment: ys there is space in wk.yml

Comment: That's weird, I mean you are telling that on that page, the view is being translated but the problem is that the form, built with formstatic is not being translated? Have you tried to put inside and outside your form something like <%= I18n.locale %> to see the value of the locale before the form is being rendered and after the form is being rendered? That may tell you where is the problem, but otherwise I'll just put a breakpointer on the first call to input, and step trace to see what's going on.

Comment: The problem was in application controller. i corrected it. Thnx for the support